# React State Update Working for First State Update but Failing on any further updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

So I have a react component that calls a function to at an interval to get balances for an account. The first load of the component successfully updates from loading and not ready to ready and pulls in the users account balances.

Upon completing a transaction and on the next account balances poll, the account balances are updated in the state and log with the correct value however not updated on the components UI (or any child components). I have also tried pulling out one of the variables, which can be seen below as pcDaiValue. This too updates on first load and first fetch of account balances, however does not update any further such as after a transaction. The state does update and logs however the UI does not update to reflect this state.

I initially believed this was a child component problem in a previous post however now I realise it is the state of the parent component not being updated.

If you look at the pcDaiValue state - it will be updated in the state but not the UI. Wondering a possible solution to this.

Any help would be appreciated here

Code below with irrelevant parts removed:

```
function ProtektDepositCard({
  children,
  item,
  lendingMarketMetrics,
  tokenPrices,
}: Props): React.Node {
 

  const [accountBalances, setAccountBalances] = useState({ready:false})
  const [pcDaiValue, setPCDaiValue] = useState(0)

  useInterval(async () => {
    (async function(){
      const newAccountBalances = await GetAccountBalances(
        web3Context.address,
        tokenPrices,
        contracts,
        [item.underlyingTokenSymbol, item.pTokenSymbol, item.reserveTokenSymbol, item.shieldTokenSymbol, item.coreTokenSymbol],
        [item.underlyingTokenDecimals, item.pTokenDecimals, item.reserveTokenDecimals, item.shieldTokenDecimals, item.coreTokenDecimals],
        [item.pTokenAddress, item.pTokenAddress, item.shieldTokenAddress, item.shieldTokenAddress, item.pTokenAddress],
        [null, item.underlyingTokenSymbol, null, item.reserveTokenSymbol, null]
      )
      console.log('retrieved account balances')
      console.log(newAccountBalances)
      console.log('retrieved pcdai')
      console.log(pcDaiValue)
      if(newAccountBalances['pcdai']){
        const pTokenValue = newAccountBalances['pcdai']['token']
        setPCDaiValue(pTokenValue)
      }
      
      setAccountBalances({...newAccountBalances})
    })();
  }, 5000)


  console.log('logging account balances')
  console.log(accountBalances)

  return ( (coverage.loading) ? <Card><Card.Body><Dimmer active loader /></Card.Body></Card> : 
    <AccordionItem
      key={accountBalances}
    >
     <div>PCDAI VALUE: {String(pcDaiValue)}</div>
      <Card className="mb-1">
        <AccordionItemHeading>
          <AccordionItemButton>
            <Card.Body>
              <Grid.Row alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                <Grid.Col width={2}>
                  <Avatar
                    imageURL={`assets/${item.coreTokenLogo}.png`}
                    style={{"verticalAlign":"middle"}}
                  />
                  <Text size="h4" align="center" RootComponent="span" className="ml-2">{item.coreToken.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                </Grid.Col>
                <Grid.Col width={3}>
                  <Avatar
                    imageURL={`assets/${item.protocolLogo}.png`}
                    style={{"verticalAlign":"middle"}}
                    size="lg"
                  />
                  <Text size="h4" align="center" RootComponent="span" className="ml-1">{item.underlyingProtocol.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                </Grid.Col>
                <Grid.Col width={2}>
                  <Text size="h4" align="center" className="mb-0">{`${numeral(coverage.netAdjustedAPR).format('0.00')}%`}</Text>
                </Grid.Col>
                <Grid.Col width={2}>
                  <Text align="center">
                    {`${numeral(coverage.pTokenTotalDepositUsd).format('$0,0a')}`}
                  </Text>
                  <Text align="center" size="sm" muted>
                    {`${numeral(parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatUnits(coverage.pTokenTotalDepositTokens,item.underlyingTokenDecimals))).format('0,0a')} ${item.underlyingTokenSymbol.toUpperCase()}`}
                  </Text>
                </Grid.Col>
                <Grid.Col width={3} className="text-center">
                  <Tag.List>
                    <Tag rounded color="purple">{item.riskTag}</Tag>
                  </Tag.List>
                </Grid.Col>
              </Grid.Row>
            </Card.Body>
          </AccordionItemButton>
        </AccordionItemHeading>
        <AccordionItemPanel>
          <ProtektHoldingSection
            item={item}
            tokenPrices={tokenPrices}
            web3Context={web3Context}
            gasPrice={gasPrice}
            contracts={contracts}
            coverage={coverage}
            claimsManager={claimsManager}
            accountBalances={accountBalances}
            onRequery={()=>{
                console.log('forcing update')
                setRequery(prevState=>prevState + 1)
              }}
            actionCount={requery}
            key={accountBalances}
          />
          <Card.Body>
            <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Col width={6}>
                <h5 className="m-0 text-muted">{`COST`}</h5>
                <p>{`${numeral(coverage.coverageFeeAPR).format('0.00')}% for ${coverage.coverageRatioDisplay} coverage`}</p>
                <h5 className="m-0 text-muted">{`BACKED BY`}</h5>
                <p>{`${item.backedByDisplay}`}</p>
              </Grid.Col>
              <Grid.Col width={6}>
                <h5 className="m-0 text-muted">{`CLAIMS`}</h5>
                <p>{`${item.claimsManagerDisplay}`}</p>
              </Grid.Col>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Col width={12}>
                <h5 className="m-0 text-muted">{`COVERAGE FOR`}</h5>
                <p>{`${item.coverageDisplay}`}</p>
              </Grid.Col>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Card.Body>
          { !web3Context.ready ?
              (<Card.Body><Text className="text-center font-italic">Connect Wallet Above<span role="img"></span></Text></Card.Body>) : 
                !accountBalances.ready ? <Card.Body><Dimmer active loader /></Card.Body> : 
                  accountBalances[item.pTokenSymbol]["token"] === "0" ?
                    renderDepositCard() :
                      (<div></div>)
          }
        </AccordionItemPanel>
      </Card>
    </AccordionItem>
  )
}

/** @component */
export default ProtektDepositCard;
```

Many thanks for any help / feedback.

## Update

Thank you for the comments so far - I have tried just incrementing a basic counter in the useInterval function and still the UI is not updated with relevant state:

```
function ProtektDepositCard({
  children,
  item,
  lendingMarketMetrics,
  tokenPrices,
}: Props): React.Node {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  useInterval(async () => {
    (async function(){
      /* other logic */
      setCounter(counter+1)
    })();
  }, 5000)


  console.log(`logging counter: ${counter}`)


  return ( 
/* Other logic */
     <div>counter: ${counter}</div>
/* Other logic */
     )

/** @component */
export default ProtektDepositCard;
```

Minimised example but still seem to be having state errors, the state logs correctly with the update counter value every 5 seconds however it is not reflected in the UI.

Comment: If `pcDaiValue` updates and you confirmed that by logging it inside of the component outside any handlers or effect, there is no way the UI will not update. Unless there is some weird memorisation in place outside of the code shown here.

Comment: Yeah this is why I'm confused also... . UI doesn't update but both logs do (the accountBalances and the individual pcDAI display the correct value). Any further ideas as to what could be causing this anywhere else?

Comment: Full repo available here [link](https://github.com/ProtektProtocol/protekt-frontend/tree/requery-state-issue) - Component in question is in ProtektDepositCard -> ProtektDepositCard

Comment: Well the console log of `pcDaiValue` is inside of an effect. Could you log it directly before the component `return` and confirm that it gets called and has a different value?

Comment: Confirmed moved it outside the effect - logs the new value but the UI does not update to reflect the new state - updated the github repo for reference also

Comment: Has this worked before and stoped working after a change? If yes, what was the change? I'm afraid to say but some of the code is very confusing due to a lack of abstraction and it is also not reproducible on another machine to debug it. Try to reduce it to a minimal example that has just enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: No hasn't worked.. will try to reformat code etc and reproduce it in a minimal example and re this at a later point - thanks for the help

Comment: @StephenByrne99 is the requery-state-issue branch supposed to actually demonstrate the problem? The logged value of pcdai is always 0, so I don't see a discrepancy between the rendered value and the state.

Comment: e.g. replace the fetching logic with a dummy, that just increments a counter using your `useInterval` hook and see if that reflects in the UI.

Comment: @ClintonChau yeah it does demonstrate the problem but it requires having a web3 wallet and some test tokens to deposit/withdraw to show the error.

Comment: @trixn Will try this later - appreciate the responses. I'm more confused as of now why the *first* call works (updates pcDaiValue from 0 -> my account balance) and subsequent calls fail, even though the state does infact update in the logs. Will come back after trying suggested methods and further debugging

Comment: @StephenByrne99 by "_even though the state does infact update_" do you mean that it simply hits the console log (every 5 seconds) or did you also confirm that it actually updates with a different value than before each time? If the value is simply always the same this is not a react issue in the first place. The comment from Clinton Chau implies that the value doesn't actually change.

Comment: @trixn confirmed it updates with the new value each time - this log is also outside the effect so it would seem it should only log when the component updates, however, the UI does not update to reflect this change.

The pcDAI value in state (logged outside effect)  goes from 0-> my balance-> mybalance -1 after withdraw

The UI reflects 0-> my balance and no further changes

Comment: @trixn Counter added to the repository along with incrementing it in the useInterval - can confirm it updates in state (by logging - every 5 seconds - outside interval) however does not update in the UI - quite perplexed by this one. Appreciate the help also so far.

Comment: @ClintonChau minimal example added if this clarifies anything

Comment: @StephenByrne99 I've cloned your repo and ran it locally and the counter value updates in the UI perfectly fine. Did you make sure you have no break point set and are looking at the correct updated version of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there appears to be a bug in the library `react-accessible-accordion` that you're using:

https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/issues/305

If you put the counter outside of the accordion, you will see it update happily. Or if you toggle the accordion, it will also update!

Comment: Thank you so much for figuring this out!